Stationarity in Markov Chains vs Time Series?
In the context of Discrete Time Markov Chains, a probability distribution $\pi$ is a stationary distribution with transition probability matrix $P$ if it satisfies the following equation:
$$\pi = \pi P$$
If $\pi$ is the stationary distribution and we start the Markov chain with initial distribution $\pi$, then for any time step $n$:
$$P(X_n = j) = \pi_j$$
Where $X_n$ is the state of the Markov chain at time $n$.
The way I interpret this, is that you start with probability distribution $\pi$ at time 0. Then apply the transition matrix $P$ any number of times. You'll always end up with the same distribution $\pi$ in the long run:
$$\pi P^n = \pi \text{ for all } n \geq 0$$
$$\pi = \pi P$$
In the context of (Continuous) Time Series ,we say that ${Xt}$ is stationary if:
$$E[X_t] = \mu$$
$$Var(X_t) = \sigma^2$$
$$Cov(X_t, X_{t+k}) = \gamma_k$$
We say that a Time Series needs to be Stationary if you intended to model it.
I have this question: Is the definition of stationarity in Markov Chains related to the definition of stationarity in Time Series?
For example - do the following equivalence conditions between Stationarity in Markov Chains and Time Series hold?
$$ Y_t = f(X_t) $$
a) Constant mean:
$$ E[Y_t] = E[f(X_t)] = \sum_{i \in S} f(i) P(X_t = i) = \sum_{i \in S} f(i) \pi_i = \mu $$
b) Constant variance:
$$ Var(Y_t) = E[(Y_t - \mu)^2] = E[f(X_t)^2] - \mu^2 $$
c) Autocovariance depends only on lag:
$$ Cov(Y_t, Y_{t+k}) = E[(Y_t - \mu)(Y_{t+k} - \mu)] $$
$$ = E[f(X_t)f(X_{t+k})] - \mu^2  = \gamma_k $$
d) Limiting Behavior:
For an ergodic Markov chain:
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} P(X_t = j | X_0 = i) = \pi_j \text{ for all } i,j \in S $$
For a Time Series:
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} E[f(X_t) | X_0 = i] = \sum_{j \in S} f(j) \pi_j = E[f(X)] $$
